# Authentication fails on Windows phone. User GUID is compared to email

Tags: cordova, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I am developing an Ionic 2 project (built on Cordova) using the Azure Active Directory ADAL plugin for Cordova:

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova

It authenticates properly on Android and IOS but fails on Windows Phone 10. I have debugged the problem all the way until the part where it goes into native code and it all seems fine.

I am internal at Microsoft and doing the authentication flow and I am actually first sent to one login screen for our mobile application before being redirected to the org sign-in page which does the two factor authentication flow. After the 2FA flow is accepted it redirects back to our application but then fails because it does a string comparison to compare the login request text to what was returned but fails because the login text is of format XXX@microsoft.com and the returned identifier is my user GUID. I have verified that this is indeed my unique user GUID but it should not be compared to my email address.

[image: Response]

Is there any work around for this issue?

**UPDATE:**
Here is the JWT. Got it from Fiddler. I saved and anonymized some of the request/responses too, let me know if you need them.

`{
   typ:"JWT",
   alg:"RS256",
   x5t:"RrQqu9rydBVRWmcocuXUb2*****",
   kid:"RrQqu9rydBVRWmcocuXUb2*****",
}
{
   aud:"5712d3fd-8e22-4040-afbf-********",
   iss:"https://sts.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-********/",
   iat:1482954230,
   nbf:1482954230,
   exp:1482958130,
   acr:"1",
   amr:[
      "pwd",
      "mfa"
   ],
   appid:"197e6baa-c9ed-4354-a561-***********",
   appidacr:"0",
   e_exp:10800,
   family_name:"****",
   given_name:"*******",
   ipaddr:"167.***.***.***",
   name:"****** ******",
   oid:"e9a9b8a5-46e5-4c78-9593-***********",
   onprem_sid:"S-1-5-21-2127521184-1604012920-1887927527-**********",
   platf:"14",
   puid:"10037FFE814B****",
   scp:"Directory.Read.All Users.Read.All",
   sub:"Jd7cxiEcj-7uVvBc-O0b8VYsT0GdXz1KDD-*******",
   tid:"72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-********",
   unique_name:"******@microsoft.com",
   upn:"******@microsoft.com",
   ver:"1.0"
}`

Comment: Can you share the claims in the token?

Comment: Where would I see that?

Comment: Take the encoded JWT token you receive, and then put it through a JWT decoder, and then hide any personal information, and then paste it here.

Comment: Updated with the data. Sorry for the delay, was tricky to get the phone to proxy to my machine and grab the network traffic.